# Why so many number of open file descriptor with MySQL 5.6.38 on centos?

Tags: mysql, centos, centos7, file-descriptor, mysql-5.6

I have two mysql instance running with --open-files-limit=65536. But it got ~193644 open file descriptor with lsof command?

```
$ lsof -n | grep mysql | wc -l
196410
$ lsof -n | grep mysql | grep ".MYI" | wc -l
83240
$ lsof -n | grep mysql | grep ".MYD" | wc -l
74053
$ sysctl fs.file-max
fs.file-max = 790612
$ lsof -n | wc -l
224647
```

Why there are so many open file descriptor? what could be the root cause of it? How to debug more?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with lsof version. I had lsof-4.87 on centos7 which is showing thread information and so it is duplicating open connections per thread. I changed lsof-4.82 & number got reduced